# emacs 23.4 mouse-2 behaviour on OS-X 10.7

Tags: macos, emacs, flyspell, ispell

how to map mouse-2 (middle button click)  to (cmd + click) or (ctrl+click) on OS X using trackpad so as to display a  popup menu under flyspell-mode.

Comment: A low acceptance demonstrates unwillingness to contribute the community.

Answer (score 16):

How about mouse-3 like Stefan suggests?

Add this to your init file:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "flyspell"
    '(progn
       (define-key flyspell-mouse-map [down-mouse-3] #'flyspell-correct-word)
       (define-key flyspell-mouse-map [mouse-3] #'undefined)))
```

Comment: This works for me. But obviously you need to run this lisp snippet at start-up; - after `flyspell` is loaded, it is too late.

Comment: This is great!  I've been modifying flyspell.el.gz each time and everytime I updated I'd lose it.

Answer (score 3):

Rather flyspell needs to be fixed to pop up its menu on mouse-3 since it's really more like a context menu.  I.e. I recommend a `M-x report-emacs-bug` about it.

Answer (score 1):

There's already an option built in for this.  Take a look at:

```
mac-emulate-three-button-mouse
```

Specifically, you should be able to just add:

```
(setq mac-emulate-three-button-mouse t)
```

In your .emacs, and then mouse-2 will be Option+Click and mouse-3 will be Cmd+Click

Comment: Note that this isn't present in GNU Emacs.

Comment: @SeanAllred To expand on that, this is for Aquamacs.